# How about a "[doc:<topic-name>]" like syntax?

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-proposals

As you may know, the `[tag:`*`<tag-name>`*`]` syntax is used to automatically link to the corresponding info page of a tag. That means

```
See the many questions tagged [tag:elephants] to learn more.
```

is displayed as

> See the many questions tagged [elephants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elephants) to learn more.

Now why don’t use the same syntax to link to a documentation topic page, such as

```
… see related documentation about [doc:html]
```

which could be displayed as

> … see related documentation about [html](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html/topics)

to readers?

---

**Edit I:** Since the a documentation page is divided into *topics* and *examples* and users are likely to link to a specific part rather than a *documentation topic page* it’s the question if this pattern would be used or an additional syntax is needed…

Comment: duplicate of http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/questions/1557/do-we-need-custom-syntax-sugar-for-topic-page-links?noredirect=1